# Swagger UI still showing the example

Tags: go, swagger, go-gin

I want to use Swagger for my RESTFul API Documentation from Go and Gin.

I have this code in main.go:
package main

```
import (
    "gowebservice/config"
    "gowebservice/controllers"

    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
    swaggerFiles "github.com/swaggo/files"
    ginSwagger "github.com/swaggo/gin-swagger"

    _ "github.com/swaggo/gin-swagger/example/basic/docs"
)

// @title Students API
// @version 1.0
// @description This is a basic API Students using Gin and Gorm.

// @host localhost:8080
// @BasePath /

func main() {
    r := gin.Default()

    config.ConnectDatabase()

    v1 := r.Group("/api/v1")
    {
        v1.GET("students/all", controllers.GetStudents)
    }

    r.GET("/swagger/*any", ginSwagger.WrapHandler(swaggerFiles.Handler))

    r.Run()
}
```

and this is my endpoint that have GET method:

```
package controllers

import (
    "gowebservice/config"
    "gowebservice/models"
    "net/http"

    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
)

// GetStudents godoc
// @Summary Show a list of students
// @Accept  json
// @Produce  json
// @Router /students [get]
func GetStudents(c *gin.Context) {
    var students []models.Student

    if err := config.DB.Find(&students).Error; err != nil {
        c.JSON(http.StatusBadRequest, gin.H{"error": "Record not found!"})
        return
    }
    c.JSON(http.StatusOK, students)
}
```

When I used `swag init` and `go run main.go`, Swagger UI still showing the example not my endpoint.

[image]

Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I ran into this too

The issue is that we imported the basic example docs:

```
import (
    ...

    _ "github.com/swaggo/gin-swagger/example/basic/docs"
)
```

You need to change that to the docs package that was generated by `swag init`.
Assuming your module name is `gowebservice`, then:

```
import (
    ...

    _ "gowebservice/docs"
)
```

Running `go run main.go` after that should make Swagger UI find your own documentation instead! :D

Comment: Oh my god thank you. You're saved my day :D @wei-liang-chew

Answer (score 0):

Whether or not these files have been generated?

```
docs.go      swagger.json swagger.yaml
```

```
 swag help init
NAME:
   swag init - Create docs.go

USAGE:
   swag init [command options] [arguments...]

OPTIONS:
   --generalInfo value, -g value       Go file path in which 'swagger general API Info' is written (default: "main.go")
   --dir value, -d value               Directory you want to parse (default: "./")
   --propertyStrategy value, -p value  Property Naming Strategy like snakecase,camelcase,pascalcase (default: "camelcase")
   --output value, -o value            Output directory for all the generated files(swagger.json, swagger.yaml and doc.go) (default: "./docs")
   --parseVendor                       Parse go files in 'vendor' folder, disabled by default
   --parseDependency                   Parse go files in outside dependency folder, disabled by default
   --markdownFiles value, --md value   Parse folder containing markdown files to use as description, disabled by default
   --generatedTime                     Generate timestamp at the top of docs.go, true by default
```

Comment: I'm already using `swag init` to generate docs.go but still not work

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you forgot that `swag init -d [...arguments]` actually expects a comma separated list of directories to scan. Do not scan only main package but others too.

For example: `swag init -d cmd/server,pkg/api,pkg/handlers`